# WordPress form structure serialized/unserializer?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, forms, serialization

I have this WordPress plugin called wp members.  I'm trying to alter its registration form a bit.  The problem is the form structure(not the actual data) is istored in the database as in serialized format.  I want to add a select input to that serialized registration form data but can't seem to figure out how.  Or is there a WordPress plugin or feature that serialized a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that everything you're looking for is right in the documentation of that plugin: http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/users-guide/registration/choosing-fields/.

> To add a new field, complete the details for the new field in the “Add
>   a Field” section.